# server send spam mail through gmail connection

Tags: email, webserver, spam-prevention

i have a batch of spam mail sent by my server (ubuntu postfix /dovecot) in my log i see that gmail (account is linked) connected and sent the mail ? what should i do to prevent this ?

```
Jul 31 12:27:5 mail postfix/smtpd[21087]: F1C88240FE1: client=mail-io0-f174.google.com[209.85.223.174], sasl_method=PLAIN, sasl_username=info@gekasmetal.gr 
Jul 31 12:27:36 mail postfix/cleanup[21091]: F1C88240FE1: message-id=<CABzTzmM_R2bTqMLziiHjaezHKXJVWXYqnuhNZaPWC5BXH6kv5w@mail.gmail.com>
Jul 31 12:27:36 mail postfix/qmgr[17904]: F1C88240FE1: from=<info@gekasmetal.gr>, size=37573, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
July 31 12:27:36 mail postfix/smtpd[21087]: disconnect from mail-io0-f174.google.com[209.85.223.174] 
Jul 31 12:27:36 mail postfix/smtp[21092]: F1C88240FE1: to=>> <ivan.atanasov@astoilov96.com>, relay=mail.astoilov96.com[195.24.40.66]:25, delay=0.85, delays=0.3/0.01/0.25/0.3, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 2.0.0 Ok: queued as ABA9D23C0098) 
Jul 31 12:27:36 mail postfix/qmgr[17904]: F1C88240FE1: removedJul 31
```

Comment: Please use code blocks to include logs and code, otherwise undesirable line breaks may occur.